# How are these algebraic and geometric notions of homotopy of maps between manifolds related?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds, and $f,g: M \to N$ smooth maps.  Denote by $(\Omega^\bullet M,\mathrm d_M)$ and $(\Omega^\bullet N, \mathrm d_N)$ the cdgas of de Rham forms in each manifold, and by $f^\ast, g^\ast : \Omega^\bullet N \to \Omega^\bullet M$ the pull-back of differential forms along each map.  Note that $\Omega^\bullet$ is a fully-faithful functor from Manifolds to CDGAs.

I have been brought up with two not-obviously-the-same notions of "homotopy" between maps $f,g$:

A *geometric homotopy* between $f,g$ is a smooth map $H : M \times [0,1] \to N$ such that $H(-,0) = f$ and $H(-,1) = g$.

An *algebraic homotopy* between $f,g$ is a map $\eta: \Omega^\bullet N \to \Omega^{\bullet - 1} M$ of graded vector spaces such that $f^\ast - g^\ast = \eta \mathrm d_N + \mathrm d_M \eta$.

I believe that the following is true.  Any geometric homotopy gives rise to an algebraic homotopy, and two geometric homotopies are homotopic iff the corresponding algebraic homotopies are <strike>homologous</strike> homotopic.  Not every algebraic homotopy comes from a geometric homotopy; rather, it should be required to satisfy some (directly-checkable) condition that says roughly that it's an "antidifferential operator".

Unfortunately, I have been unable to really convince myself of either of the above beliefs.  Probably this is textbook material, and so maybe my question is to be pointed to the correct textbook.  But really my question is:

> How, explicitly, are the above notions of homotopy between maps related?  What extra conditions (if any?) should be put on an algebraic homotopy in order for it to be "geometric"?

It is somewhat embarrassing not to know the sharp relationship between the above concepts, but this is one of the many parts of mathematics that I have picked up largely from conversations and working on the examples that come from particular research questions, and not from ever formally learning such material.

Comment: The claim "any geometric homotopy gives rise to an algebraic homotopy" is true.  An explicit construction can be found in Lemma 20 here:  http://www.thehcmr.org/issue1_2/poincare_lemma.pdf

The obvious thing to try to do to get geometric homotopies from algebraic ones is to try to write down a vector field on $N$ and flow $M$ along it, but this must be hopeless if $M$ is not compact, right?  So perhaps you want compactness as a hypothesis.

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ are compact and simply connected, it seems like Hurewicz should imply that algebraic homotopy implies geometric homotopy, no?  I'm not a topologist, but that may be the place to start.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the meaning of "two geometric homotopies are homotopic iff the corresponding algebraic homotopies are homologous". To me, "homologous" for maps of chain complexes means that they induce the same map on homology. But these algebraic homotopies certainly aren't chain maps. 

Comment: I agree with Mark---I'm confused about the meaning of paragraph 4.  Upon further reflection, it seems likely that $f$ and $g$ can be algebraically homotopic (your definition) without being homotopic if $M$ or $N$ is not simply connected.  

Comment: I took homologous to mean the following; hopefully Theo will correct me if I'm wrong.  Given chain complexes $C^\bullet, D^\bullet$, there is a chain complex $\operatorname{Hom}^\bullet(C^\bullet, D^\bullet)$ whose $i$-th degree is given by tuples of maps $C^j\to D^{i+j}$ (this is the inner hom in the category of chain complexes), and the differential is given $(f^j)\mapsto (f^j\circ d+(-1)^i d\circ f^j)$.  A chain map is a degree $0$ closed elt; a homotopy is a degree $1$ elt, and two homotopies are homologous if their difference is exact in this complex.

Comment: (Above $(-1)^i$ should be $(-1)^{i+1}$.)

Comment: @Mark and @SPG: sorry, I should have just said "homotopic" there too.  @Daniel understood what I mean.  I will change that.  I used "homologous" only to emphasize that by the time I've over working with $\Omega^\bullet$, I'm manipulating things that represent things in homology.

Comment: @Daniel:  I'm fine adding compactness hypotheses if you want them.  But I still don't see how to turn an algebraic homotopy into a vector field, generically.  In particular, in examples I've thought about the algebraic homotopies that I construct are not derivations, but compositions of a derivation and then an integral from $0$ to $1$ of a certain value.  In any case, the homotopy is lowers (cohomological) grading by $1$, whereas for something to generate a flow that can build a geometric homotopy it must be a grading-$0$ derivation.

Comment: I guess if you can turn the algebraic homotopy into a derivation in a reasonably canonical way, then you can take its commutator with the de Rham $d$, which is also a derivation, and in that way get a grading-$0$ derivation.

Comment: Oh, incidentally, @Daniel's linked article is quite good.  So that answers one direction of the first question (in a way that I think I should have thought of).

Comment: What is a precise formulation of the fully-faithfulness of $\Omega^{\bullet}$? I.e., what are the source and target categories in this assertion?

Comment: @Mossbrugger: I think I can get away with the following. Recall that the category of smooth (Hausdorff, second-countable) manifolds is full and faithful in the (opposite) category of commutative algebras, by taking $C^\infty$. So I take the source as second-countable smooth manifolds, and I will try to take the target to be all commutative dgas (which is horribly large, but I didn't say anything about essential surjectivity). Faithful is clear, by restricting just to $\Omega^0 = C^\infty$. But Full is also, because $\Omega^\bullet$ is generated as a cdga by $\Omega^0$, and then use degrees.

Comment: Whenever I can't remember how to prove that deRham things play nice with homotopies, I start over from the homotopy equivalence $I\times M\to M$ for $I$ something roomy, smooth, and contractible --- with cylinder objects, in model-cat-speak. Now I'm suspecting that somewhere between algebraic homotopies and geometric-induced algebraic homotopies, there's probably an equivalence of cdgas $\Omega^\dot (M) \to \Omega^\dot (I)\otimes \Omega^\dot (M)$, for some flexible contractible algebra $\Omega^\dot (I)$.

Comment: er... that didn't typeset like I wanted. }:(

Answer (score 10):

There is a simple way to understand the implication "geometric implies algebraic homotopy" if you remember that $\Omega^*(M \times I)$ is the (projective) tensor product of $\Omega^*(M)$ and $\Omega^*(I)$ of chain-complexes. Take the chain map $Int:\Omega^*(I) \to C^*(I)$ given by integration, where $C^*(I)$ is the simplicial cochain complex of the 1-simplex $I$ (of total dimension 3).

Then a geometric homotopy, composed with $Int$ gives a chain map
$$ \Omega^*(N) \to \Omega^*(M) \otimes C^*(I)$$
Unravelling this map into its 3 components, corresponding to the two 0-simplices and the 1-simplex of $I$, you get a triple $(f^*,g^*,\eta)$ which is precisely an algebraic homotopy.

It's very hard to go back since an algebraic homotopy is very weak information, it exists if and only if $f$ and $g$ induce the same map on de Rham cohomology (since these are chain complexes over a field).

One thing to do is to pull back the dga structure on $\Omega^*(I)$ to an $A_\infty$-structure on $C^*(I)$ via $Int$ (and a choice of a homotopy inverse). Instead of just an algebraic homotopy, you could then require an $A_\infty$ map 
$$ \Omega^*(N) \to \Omega^*(M) \otimes C^*(I)$$
which extends your given pair $(f^*,g^*)$ on the boundary (note that by construction, an example comes from a geometric homotopy). If $M$ and $N$ are nilpotent, this should guarantee a homotopy on the "realifications" by rational (or better: real) homotopy theory.

For example, this should detect the Hopf maps between spheres but none of their suspensions (since these are torsion).